# В древовидной модели QAbstractItemModel не отображаются дочерние элементы

Tags: qt, mvc, treeview

Реализую собственную древовидную модель-представление Qt. Модель наследую как положено от класса QAbstractItemModel. Я поставил 4 столбца в модели, переопределив метод класса QAbstractItemModel

```
int MusicModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const{
    return 4;
}
```

Метод data переопределил следующим образом:

```
QVariant MusicModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const{
//    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole){
        if (index.isValid()){
            int column = index.column();
            Item *item = static_cast<Item *>(index.internalPointer());
            switch (column){
            case 0:
                return item->name();
            case 1:
                if(item->toSong()) return item->toSong()->time();
                break;
            case 2:
                if(item->toSong()) return item->toSong()->rating();
                break;
            case 3:
                qDebug() << QTime::currentTime().toString("HH:mm:ss") << item->name() << column;
                if(item->toSong()) return item->toSong()->name();
                if(item->toArtist()) return item->name();
                break;
            }
        }
        return QVariant();
//    }
}
```

Пока не акцентирую внимание на ролях, отображаю для всех ролей одинаково.
Иерархия выглядит следующим образом:

0 уровень m_root

1 уровень Artist

2 уровнь Album

3 уровень Song

Столкнулся с проблемой, когда пытаюсь отобразить 3 уровень. Он попросту не отображается, если я пытаюсь взаимодействовать с 4-ым столбцом в методе data. Иными словами, если убрать строчку `if(item->toSong()) return item->toSong()->name();` или добавить 5-ый столбец (columnCount вернёт 5). Только тогда 3-ий уровень вложенности сможет открыться в представлении.
Сейчас же ситуация выглядит так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы можете заметить, Есть 2 артиста: "ИМЯ" и "Second_a". Также есть 4 альбома у первого артиста ("m2", "m3", "m4", "4-ый"). Но у меня не получается раскрыть альбом "m2", чтобы увидеть вложенные песни. Таким образом, не удаётся отредактировать последний столбец модели...
Возниакет вопрос: Почему на последнем уровне вложенности у меня не получается редактировать последний элемент?

Ниже прикладываю код проекта. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

musicmodel.h:

```
#ifndef MUSICMODEL_H
#define MUSICMODEL_H
#include <QAbstractItemModel>
#include <item.h>

class MusicModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Item *m_root;
public:
    MusicModel();
    MusicModel(Item *_m_root){ m_root = _m_root;};
    QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &index) const;
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole);
    bool insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex());
    bool removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex());
};

#endif // MUSICMODEL_H
```

musicmodel.cpp:

```
#include "musicmodel.h"
#include <QDebug>

MusicModel::MusicModel()
{
    m_root = new Item;
}

QModelIndex MusicModel::index(int row,int column,const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Item *parentItem = m_root;

    if(parent.isValid())
        parentItem = static_cast<Item*>(parent.internalPointer());
    if (parentItem->childAt(row))
        return createIndex(row, column, parentItem->childAt(row));

    return QModelIndex();
}

QModelIndex MusicModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const{
    if (!index.isValid())return QModelIndex();
    Item *childItem = static_cast<Item *>(index.internalPointer());
    Item *parent = childItem->parent();
    if ((parent == m_root) || !(parent)) return QModelIndex();
    Item *grandparent = parent->parent();
    return createIndex(grandparent->indexOf(parent), 0, parent);
}

int MusicModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const{
    Item *parentItem = m_root;
    if(parent.isValid())
        parentItem = static_cast<Item *>(parent.internalPointer());
    return parentItem->childCount();
}

int MusicModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const{
    return 4;
}

QVariant MusicModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const{
//    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole){
        if (index.isValid()){
            int column = index.column();
            Item *item = static_cast<Item *>(index.internalPointer());
            switch (column){
            case 0:
                return item->name();
            case 1:
                if(item->toSong()) return item->toSong()->time();
                break;
            case 2:
                if(item->toSong()) return item->toSong()->rating();
                break;
            case 3:
                qDebug() << QTime::currentTime().toString("HH:mm:ss") << item->name() << column;
                if(item->toSong()) return item->toSong()->name();
                if(item->toArtist()) return item->name();
                break;
            }
        }
        return QVariant();
//    }
//    else if(role == Qt::EditRole){

//    }
}

Qt::ItemFlags MusicModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const{
    return QAbstractItemModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsEditable;
}

bool MusicModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role){

}

bool MusicModel::insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent){

}

bool MusicModel::removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent){

}
```

Item.h:

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H
#include <QList>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QTime>
#include <QDataStream>

class Artist;
class Album;
class Song;

class Item {
public:
    Item();
    Item(const QString &);
    ~Item();
    Item *parent() const;
    void setParent(Item *);
    void insertChild(Item *, int position = -1);
    Item *takeChild(int);
    Item *childAt(int) const;
    int indexOf(Item*) const;
    int childCount() const;
    QString name() const{ return m_name; }
    void setName(const QString & _name){ m_name = _name; }
    virtual Artist *toArtist() { return 0; }
    virtual Album *toAlbum() { return 0; }
    virtual Song *toSong() { return 0; }
private:
    Item *m_parent;
    QList<Item*> m_children;
    QString m_name;
    QString m_comment;
};

class Artist : public Item{
    QPixmap _picture;
    QString _country;
    QString _comment;
public:
    Artist() : Item() {}
    Artist(const QString &n) : Item(n) {}
    const QPixmap picture() const{ return _picture; }
    void setPicture(const QPixmap &_p) { _picture = _p; }
    const QString country() const{ return _country; }
    void setCountry(const QString &_c) { _country = _c; }
    const QString comment() const{ return _comment; }
    void setComment(const QString &_c) { _comment = _c; }
    Artist *toArtist() { return this; }
    Album *toAlbum() { return 0; }
    Song *toSong() { return 0; }
};

class Album : public Item{
    int _year;
    QPixmap _picture;
    QString _genre;
    QString _comment;
public:
    Album() : Item() {}
    Album(const QString &n) : Item(n) {}
    int year() const{ return _year; }
    void setYear(int _y) { _year = _y; }
    const QPixmap picture() const{ return _picture; }
    void setPicture(const QPixmap &_p) { _picture = _p; }
    const QString genre() const{ return _genre; }
    void setGenre(const QString &_g) { _genre = _g; }
    const QString comment() const{ return _comment; }
    void setComment(const QString &_c) { _comment = _c; }
    Artist *toArtist() { return 0; }
    Album *toAlbum() { return this; }
    Song *toSong() { return 0; }
};

class Song : public Item{
    QTime _time;
    int _rating;
    QString _comment;
public:
    Song() : Item() {}
    Song(const QString &n) : Item(n) {}
    const QTime time() const{ return _time; }
    void setTime(const QTime &_t) { _time = _t; }
    int rating() const{ return _rating; }
    void setRating(int _r) { _rating = _r; }
    QString comment() const{ return _comment; }
    void setComment(const QString &_c) { _comment = _c; }
    Artist *toArtist() { return 0; }
    Album *toAlbum() { return 0; }
    Song *toSong() { return this; }
};

QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream &, const Artist &);
QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream &, const Album &);
QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream &, const Song &);
QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream &, Artist &);
QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream &, Album &);
QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream &, Song &);
#endif // ITEM_H
```

Item.cpp:

```
#include "item.h"
#include <QDebug>


Item::Item(){
    m_parent = 0;
    m_name = "Безымянный";
}

Item::Item(const QString &name){
    m_parent = 0;
    m_name = name;
}

Item::~Item(){
    qDebug() << "delete" << name();
    int count = childCount();
    if (m_parent)m_parent->m_children.takeAt(m_parent->indexOf(this));
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) delete childAt(0);
}

void Item::insertChild(Item *child, int position){
    if(position < 0)position = childCount();
    if (!m_children.contains(child))m_children.insert(position, child);
    if (child->parent() != this)child->setParent(this);
}

Item *Item::takeChild(int position){
    Item *child = m_children.takeAt(position);
    child->setParent(0);
    return child;
}

void Item::setParent(Item *_parent){
    if (_parent){
        if (m_parent){
            m_parent->takeChild(m_parent->indexOf(this));
        }
        m_parent = _parent;
        m_parent->insertChild(this);
    }
    m_parent = _parent;
}

Item *Item::parent() const{
    return m_parent;
}


Item *Item::childAt(int position) const{
    if (position < 0 || position >= childCount()) return nullptr;
    return m_children.at(position);
}

int Item::indexOf(Item* el) const{
    return m_children.indexOf(el);
}

int Item::childCount() const{
    return m_children.size();
}

QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream &stream, const Artist &artist) {

    stream << artist.name() << artist.picture() << artist.country()
           << artist.comment();
    // serialize children
    int cnt = artist.childCount();
    stream << cnt;
    for(int i=0; i<cnt; ++i){
        Album *album = artist.childAt(i)->toAlbum();
        if(album) stream << *album;
    }
    return stream;
}

QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream &stream, const Album &album){

    stream << album.name() << album.year() << album.picture()
           << album.genre() << album.comment();
    int cnt = album.childCount();
    stream << cnt;
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++){
        Song *song = album.childAt(i)->toSong();
        if (song) stream << *song;
    }
    return stream;
}

QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream &stream, const Song &song){

    stream << song.name() << song.time() << song.rating()
           << song.comment();
    return stream;
}

QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream &stream, Artist &artist){
    QString name;
    QPixmap picture;
    QString country;
    QString comment;
    stream >> name >> picture >> country >> comment;
    artist.setName(name);
    artist.setPicture(picture);
    artist.setCountry(country);
    artist.setComment(comment);
    int cnt;
    stream >> cnt;
    Album *album;
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++){
        album = new Album;
        stream >> *album;
        artist.insertChild(album);
    }
    return stream;
}

QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream &stream, Album &album){
    QString name;
    int year;
    QPixmap picture;
    QString genre;
    QString comment;
    stream >> name >> year >> picture >> genre >> comment;
    album.setName(name);
    album.setYear(year);
    album.setPicture(picture);
    album.setGenre(genre);
    album.setComment(comment);
    int cnt;
    stream >> cnt;
    Song *song;
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++){
        song = new Song;
        stream >> *song;
        album.insertChild(song);
    }
    return stream;
}

QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream &stream, Song &song){
    QString name;
    QTime time;
    int rating;
    QString comment;
    stream >> name >> time >> rating >> comment;
    song.setName(name);
    song.setTime(time);
    song.setRating(rating);
    song.setComment(comment);
    return stream;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QList>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <item.h>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <musicmodel.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
//    MainWindow w;
//    w.show();
//    QList<int> l;
//    l.append(1);
//    l.append(2);
//    l.insert(-10, 0);
//    qDebug() << l.takeAt(0);
//    qDebug() << l.takeAt(0);
//    qDebug() << l.indexOf(1);
    Item *_m1 = new Artist;
    Artist *m1 = _m1->toArtist();
    m1->setComment("comment0");
    m1->setCountry("RUSSIA");
    m1->setPicture(QPixmap());
    m1->setName("ИМЯ");
    Item *_m2 = new Album("m2");
    Album *m2 = _m2->toAlbum();
    m2->setComment("comment1");
    m2->setYear(1993);
    m2->setGenre("ROCK");
//    QString name = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, "Open", QDir::currentPath());
//    qDebug() << name;
//    m2->setPicture(QPixmap(name));
    m2->setPicture(QPixmap("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Chrysanthemum.jpg"));
    Album *m3 = new Album("m3");
    Album *m4 = new Album("m4");
    Item *_m5 = new Song("m5");
    Song *m5 = _m5->toSong();
    m5->setTime(QTime());
    m5->setRating(4);
    m5->setComment("comment2");
    Song *m6 = new Song("m6");
    m1->insertChild(m2);
//    m1->insertChild(m4);
    m4->setParent(m1);
    m2->insertChild(m5);
    m4->insertChild(m6);
    m1->insertChild(m3, 1);
//    m6->setParent(m3);
    qDebug() << m1->childCount();
//    qDebug() << m1->childAt(1)->name();
//    delete m4;
//    qDebug() << m3->parent() << m3 << m3->childCount() << m3->name();
//    Item *cur;
//    qDebug() << m1->childAt(0)->name();
//    cur = m1->takeChild(0);
//    qDebug() << cur->name() << cur->parent() << "cur";
//    qDebug() << m1->indexOf(m4) << "index";
    qDebug() << m1->childAt(0)->name() << m1->childAt(0)->toAlbum() << m1->comment() << m1->country() << m1->picture();
    qDebug() << m2->year() << m2->comment() << m2->picture() << m2->genre();
    qDebug() << m1->parent() << m1 << m1->childCount() << m1->name();
    qDebug() << m2->parent()->name() << m2 << m2->childCount() << m2->name();
    qDebug() << m3->parent()->name() << m3 << m3->childCount() << m3->name();
    qDebug() << m4->parent()->name() << m4 << m4->childCount() << m4->name();
    qDebug() << m5->parent()->name() << m5 << m5->childCount() << m5->name()
             << m5->time() << m5->rating() << m5->comment();
    qDebug() << (m5 == nullptr);
    qDebug() << m6->parent()->name() << m6 << m6->childCount() << m6->name();
    qDebug() << m1->childAt(1)->name();
    QFile file("D:/Qt/Code/Music/new.txt");
    QDataStream stream(&file);
    if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
        stream << *m1;
    }
    file.close();
    Artist *artist = new Artist;
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        stream >> *artist;
    }
    qDebug() << "Deserialization";
    qDebug() << artist->childCount();
    qDebug() << artist->childAt(0)->name() << artist->childAt(0)->toAlbum()
             << artist->comment() << artist->country() << artist->picture();
    Album *album_1;
    album_1 = artist->childAt(0)->toAlbum();
    qDebug() << album_1->year() << album_1->comment()
             << album_1->picture() << album_1->genre();
    qDebug() << artist->parent() << artist << artist->childCount() << artist->name();
    qDebug() << album_1->parent()->name() << album_1
             << album_1->childCount() << album_1->name();
    Album *album_2;
    album_2 = artist->childAt(1)->toAlbum();
    qDebug() << album_2->parent()->name() << album_2
             << album_2->childCount() << album_2->name();
    Album *album_3;
    album_3 = artist->childAt(2)->toAlbum();
    qDebug() << album_3->parent()->name() << album_3
             << album_3->childCount() << album_3->name();
    Song *song_1, *song_2;
    song_1 = album_1->childAt(0)->toSong();
    qDebug() << song_1->parent()->name() << song_1 << song_1->childCount()
             << song_1->name() << song_1->time() << song_1->rating()
             << song_1->comment();
    qDebug() << (song_1 == nullptr);
    song_2 = album_3->childAt(0)->toSong();
    qDebug() << song_2->parent()->name() << song_2
             << song_2->childCount() << song_2->name();
    qDebug() << artist->childAt(1)->name();

    Item *root = new Item;
    root->insertChild(artist);
    Artist *artist2 = new Artist;
    artist2->setName("Second_a");
    artist2->setParent(root);
    MusicModel *model = new MusicModel(root);
    QModelIndex index_a1 = model->index(0,0,QModelIndex());
    QModelIndex index_a2 = model->index(1,0,QModelIndex());
    Album *album4 = new Album("4-ый");
    artist->insertChild(album4);
    qDebug() << "Артист 1" << static_cast<Item*>((index_a1).internalPointer())->name()
             << "Родитель" << static_cast<Item*>((model->parent(index_a1)).internalPointer())
             << "Строк" << model->rowCount(index_a1) << "Колонок" << model->columnCount(index_a1);
    qDebug() << "Артист 2" << static_cast<Item*>((index_a2).internalPointer())->name()
             << "Строк" << model->rowCount(index_a2) << "Колонок" << model->columnCount(index_a2);
    QModelIndex index_a_1_1 = model->index(0, 0, index_a1);
    qDebug() << "Альбом 1" << static_cast<Item*>((index_a_1_1).internalPointer())->name()
             << "Родитель" << static_cast<Item*>((model->parent(index_a_1_1)).internalPointer())->name()
             << "Строк" << model->rowCount(index_a_1_1) << "Колонок" << model->columnCount(index_a_1_1);
    QModelIndex index_a_1_2 = model->index(1, 0, index_a1);
    qDebug() << "Альбом 2" << static_cast<Item*>((index_a_1_2).internalPointer())->name()
             << "Строк" << model->rowCount(index_a_1_2) << "Колонок" << model->columnCount(index_a_1_2);
    QModelIndex index_a_1_3 = model->index(2, 0, index_a1);
    qDebug() << "Альбом 3" << static_cast<Item*>((index_a_1_3).internalPointer())->name()
             << "Строк" << model->rowCount(index_a_1_3) << "Колонок" << model->columnCount(index_a_1_3);
    QModelIndex index_a_2_1 = model->index(0, 0, index_a_1_1);
    qDebug() << "Песня 1" << static_cast<Item*>((index_a_2_1).internalPointer())->name()
             << "Родитель" << static_cast<Item*>((model->parent(index_a_2_1)).internalPointer())->name()
             << "Строк" << model->rowCount(index_a_2_1) << "Колонок" << model->columnCount(index_a_2_1);
    QTreeView *tree = new QTreeView;
    tree->setModel(model);
    tree->show();
    /*
    QFile file("D:/Qt/Code/Music/new.txt");
    QDataStream stream(&file);
    if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append)){
        stream << QString("ads") << 123 << QString("last");
        if (stream.status() != QDataStream::Ok){
            qDebug() << "Ошибка записи.";
        }
    }
    file.close();
    QString first, last, another;
    int middle;
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        stream >> first >> middle >> last >> another;
//        stream >> middle;
//        stream >> last;
//        stream >> another;
    }
    qDebug() << first << middle << last << another;
    file.close();
    */
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Закиньте проект на какой-нибудь git репозитарий. в таком виде врядли кто-то захочет ковыряться

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось довольно простым. Нужно было оставить лишь роль `Qt::DisplayRole` и возможно `Qt::EditRole` в функции data. Это решает мою проблему с невозможностью развернуть дерево на всех уровнях.